# C/C++: maximum size of errno-associated strings (at compile-time)

Tags: c++, c

### Question

Is there any way to get the maximum size of any string correlated with `errno` at compile time (at preprocessor time would be even better)? E.g. an upper bound on `strlen(strerror(errno))`?

### My Thoughts

The best I can think of is running a program to do a brute-force search over the range of an int, over each locale, to get the string associated with each {errno, locale} pair, get its size, and generate a header on that system, then hooking that into e.g. a makefile or autoconf or whatever. I can't think of a better way to do it, but it seems ridiculous that it would be so: the standard library for a system has that information built-in, if only implicitly. Is there really no good way to get that information?

I've been told that C and/or C++ standards don't permit errno strings to be generated at runtime, with specific-to-circumstance messages (for example, `strerror(EINVAL)` also using other metadata which was set at the same time as `errno`), and I've never heard of an implementation like that.

### Motivation

For context, what I specifically wanted (but I think this question is valuable in a more general way, as was discussed amongst the comments) that led to this question was to be able to use the error string associated with `errno` in the syscall/function `writev`. In my specific usecase, I was using strings out of `argv` *and* `errno`-linked strings. This set my "worst-case" length to `ARG_MAX` + `some max errno string length` + `size of my constant small error message`).

Every *nix document I've consulted seems to indicate `writev` will (or "may", for what little good that difference makes in this case) error out with `errno` set to `EINVAL` if the sum of the `iov_len` values overflows `SSIZE_MAX`. Intuitively, I know every `errno` string I've seen is very short, and in practice this is a non-issue. But I don't want my code mysteriously failing to print an error at all on some system if it's possible for this assumption to be false. So I wrote code to handle such a case - but at the same time, it seemed better to exclude that code on platforms which don't need it.

The combined input of the answers and comments so far is making me lean towards thinking that in my particular use-case, the "right" solution is to just truncate obscenely long messages - but this is why I asked the question how I did initially: such information would also help select a size for a buffer to `strerror_r`/`strerror_s` (*nix/Windows respectively), and even a negative answer (e.g. "you can't do it") is educational.

### Related

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856387/maximum-size-of-message-for-strerror-r-on-vxworks) contains answers for the strings given by `strerror_r` on VxWorks, but I don't feel comfortable generalizing that to all systems.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages!

Comment: @Olaf While I generally appreciate your efforts in making this distinction clear, I believe that in this case, speaking of C and C++ together is legit as the `errno` concept is used by both of them alike. Choosing either tag over the other one would be arbitrary.

Comment: Wouldn't it also depend on the locale being used?

Comment: @5gon12eder: I'm afraid I have to disagree. The `errno` & related are part of the C compatibility interface and the libc, thus not native C++/libc++. Said that, please notice the question explicitly references the C standard.

Comment: Can you choose your own max, and clip the error messages at runtime?

Comment: I might be missing something, but an error message larger than ssize_t seems completely crazy on any platform where ssize_t is larger than int8_t.

Comment: @Olaf I worded it that way because of an assumption that C++ just followed whatever the C standard says, or that failing that, it would at most be _less_ permissive rather than _more_ permissive vs. the C standard. Still, I've re-worded that phrase to now include both. Would you say that this question has no meaningful relevance to the C++ world, or that C++ would have a substantially different answer than the answer for C?

Comment: @MarkNunberg Yes. I tried to word the question to account for that - feel free to suggest/edit clarifications to the wording if that's not clear.

Comment: @mtraceur: I really think you should have left it with the C standard. Adding C++ makes the question possibly even broader as now C++ features come into play. If you want a C++ solution, though, just remove the C tag. Either way, a solution can very well depend on the language you use. Notice that identical syntax does not imply identical semantics!

Comment: @xrgb Yes - I can work around the entire problem at runtime, whether that way or without even clipping them by wrapping writev. But knowing at compile-time would allow preprocessor macros to exclude the unnecessary code, which I think is valuable for several reasons.

Comment: The C (and I suspect the C++) standard will not help concerning `SSIZE_MAX` as it does not define `SSIZE_MAX`.  If `SSIZE_MAX` is important to your code, suggest tagging the environment of interest that defines it.

Comment: Note, runtime generation *does* happen for out-of-range values (> 134 on Linux), but this generates smaller strings than many in-range values. But including additional metadata is forbidden because there's no saying when or whether the error actually occured.

Comment: @zneak: Actually, if I remember the standards right, `ssize_t` must always be larger than `int8_t`: `ssize_t` is the signed equivalent of `size_t`, and `size_t` is bound to at a minimum support values up to `65 535`, and the latest POSIX/SUS require `ssize_t` to at least support values up to `32 767`. However, consider that there are multiple maxima going into a typical error message's maximum size: e.g. `ARG_MAX + MAGICAL_ERR_STR_MAX + sizeof(my_biggest_additional_error_text) - 1` together must be smaller than `SSIZE_MAX` for it to be safe to ignore the possibility of overflowing `SSIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @chux: While the `SSIZE_MAX` and `writev` details were an example of my current usecase, the question itself is more broadly relevant: if I were to port my code to Windows' `WriteFileGather` or whatever, the constants to check against change, but knowing the maximum length of an error string remains relevant "would be nice to have" information.

Comment: @mtraceur Certainly `strlen(any_string) <= SIZE_MAX` is true.  `strlen(strerror(errno))` is not defined by C to be more constrained.  So that the portable limit.

Comment: @chux: Sure, that's a the maximum possible limit that logically follows from the standards' definitions of those functions, yes: But surely the existence of unknown-unknowns justifies asking, in case there was some other, smaller limit. Also note: you can write portable code which takes advantage of smaller non-portable limits if those limits have a portable way to check for their presence (e.g. imagine a `fooUNIX` which defines a macro `ERR_STR_LEN_MAX` and a macro `__FOO_UNIX` that can be checked for with an `#ifdef`.)

Comment: @Olaf: After some serious consideration, I have to disagree in this special case, because the question also has an "at compile time" limitation: I know C++ can do some serious magic with template metaprogramming and the like, but it doesn't seem like (especially given the answers that come in), that there's a difference between the two languages in this regard: the answer more or less seems to come down to "no" or "no (except maybe on some systems there's a preprocessor macro defined that gives an upper bound)", which is equally applicable to either language.

Comment: @mtraceur I agree this is a good post (hence my UV), it is just that, IMO, there is no possible answer that is highly satisfactory.  It is certainty reasonable to survey a number of diverse systems, check their max error message lengths, and use that limit, with x4 for margin.  In this special case of error handling, the whole system is in question and a excessively long error message should be viewed with suspicion.  IMO, it makes sense to limit to few 100 bytes and print a truncated valid message rather than print a 2G byte message from a de-graded system.

Comment: @mtraceur: There might be a meta-programming solution: Write a program which – at build-time – gets all strings, calculates the length and passes a macro with the max. length to the module or generates a config-file. With a proper build-system, this can be written directly in the build-script. SCons comes into mind, as that is written in Python and the build-scripts are actually Python programs with full access to the features. Doner properly, this is only run once per clean build, so no real impact on incremental builds.

Comment: Based on answers going in different directions, could you clarify something: is your concern that some system might have some errno string whose length is close to `SSIZE_MAX` (incredibly unlikely)?  Or are you planning to write a number of bytes that is already close to `SSIZE_MAX`, and you are concerned that a moderately long errno string might push you over?

Comment: @chux: I see. I suspected that I wouldn't find a satisfactory answer, but a definitive "no" answer is still valuable, I think. As to the error printing, I agree: a system with huge error messages shouldn't really be "trusted". The more I think about it the more I'm starting to fathom just how ridiculous my concern was: honoring an error message which for some reason turns out to be huge may well be the wrong behavior, and I've been unquestioningly thinking it's the "correct" thing for me to account for huge error messages. Truncation may well be the most "right" thing to do in such cases.

Comment: @Olaf: Agreed re: metaprogramming, but to clarify my last comment specifically mentioned C++'s _template_ metaprogramming, in the sense that the only way I could see this developing different answers for the two languages (C vs. C++) was if C++'s templates or other features could be abused to do that search at compile-time, from within the source of the being-compiled program. I think(?) any external program, while an interesting solution, would be outside the scope of the question, since my question explicitly asks if there's a better way than extrernal bruteforce search to generate a header.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The latter was the line of reasoning that initially caused me to ask the question, though I thought the question was more valuable as stated. Still, I'll add it to the "Motivation" section in my question, as it's likely useful contextual information.

Comment: @mtraceur: I did not reply to your comment. It was just an idea which came into mind, unrelated to the preceeding comment. (btw., typo: "Doner" should be "Done"; not related to the tasty turkish food - maybe I was a bit hungry:-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The C library that you build against may not be the same (ABI compatible C library maybe used) or even exact version of the C library (On GNU/Linux consider glibc 2.2.5 vs. glibc 2.23) that you run against, therefore computing the maximum size of the locale-dependent string returned from `strerror` can only be done at runtime during process execution. On top of this the locale translations may be updated on the target system at any time, and this again invalidates any pre-computation of this upper bound.

Unfortunately there is no guarantee that the values returned by `strerror` are constant for the lifetime of the process, and so they may also change at a later time, thus invalidating any early computation of the bound.

I suggest using [strerror_r](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html) to save the error string and avoid any issues with non-multi-thread aware libraries that might call sterror and possibly change the result of the string as you are copying it. Then instead of translating the string on-the-fly you would use the saved result, and potentially truncate to `SSIZE_MAX` (never going to happen in reality).

Comment: +1, though note that having an upper bound would be great for choosing a size for the buffer passed to `strerror_r` as well, reducing the need for runtime logic. Also, I had considered and was aware of the maxima-could-change-out-from-under-your-program situation - but I was hoping that there was some standard limitation, or at least platform-specific macros we could check on at least some systems, that could've possibly made that a non-issue for at least some systems, hence the question.

Comment: In particular, it's noteworthy that POSIX (per your link) allows `strerror_r` to fail with an `ERANGE` if the buffer given to it isn't big enough: my reading suggests that an implementation which checks for the length first, and errors out without writing anything, would be standard-compliant. I want to believe no implementation does this, or I'm misreading, but if so, then it seems without knowing an upper bound it seems we must either err on the side of a moderately generous buffer to hold it, or a loop to reallocate until it returns success?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the `strerrorbuf` was modified by a call to `strerror_r` which returned `ERANGE`. So you must be prepared to handle the various combinations of returns as specified in the normative text of the standard.

Comment: After a few days of contemplation, I am (tentatively) accepting this answer, because it is both 1) general and 2) provides the most thorough explanations as to why such information could not (and perhaps should not) be available at compile time for many implementations.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware that the C or C++ standards make any assertions regarding the length of these messages. The platforms you're interested in might provide some stronger implementation-defined guarantees, though.

For example, for POSIX systems, I found the following in [`limits.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html).

> The following constants shall be defined on all implementations in `<limits.h>`:
>
> - […]
> - `{NL_TEXTMAX}`
>     Maximum number of bytes in a message string.
>     Minimum Acceptable Value: `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}`

I believe that error messages produced by `strerror` would fall into this category.

That said, I'm unable to get this macro on my system. However, I do have `_POSIX2_LINE_MAX` (from `<unistd.h>`). It is `#define`d to 2048. Since the standard only says that this is a lower bound, that might not be too helpful, though.

Comment: I was able to get `NL_TEXTMAX` defined by defining `_GNU_SOURCE`. I therefore suspect that a sufficiently "high" value defined for `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` would get it included. Anyway, the value was `0x7fffffff`, or 2147483647. Not too inspiring on its own - though `SSIZE_MAX` was twice as wide (8 more trailing `f` digits).

Comment: For the record, I +1'ed this as well, and I appreciated the information given with regard to my specific use-case. Even though I currently accepted another answer, I think this is the next-best answer, because it covers information not given in the main answer, and does suggest (albeit inconclusively) that some implementations, or other standards built on top of the language specifications, might in fact define some sort of upper limits.

Answer (score 3):

[The standards make no guarantees](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) about the size limits of the null-terminated string returned by `strerror`.

In practice, this is never going to be an issue. However, if you're that paranoid about it, I would suggest that you just copy the string returned from `strerr` and clamp its length to `SSIZE_MAX` before passing it to `writev`.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that the standard makes no guarantee in this area, but I don't think cppreference.com is an authoritative reference for that.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to assume that `SSIZE_MAX` will be greater than the longest string (character array) that strerror returns in a normal C or C++ system.  This is because usable system memory (usable directly by your C program) can be no larger than `SIZE_MAX` (an unsigned integer value) and `SSIZE_MAX` will have at least the same number of bits so using 2's compliment math to account for the signed nature of SSIZE_MAX (and ssize_t) SSIZE_MAX will be at least 1/2 the size of system memory.

Comment: Detail: "This is because usable system memory (usable directly by your C program) can be no larger than SIZE_MAX" --> disagree,  `SIZE_MAX` is the max value of an array index for a _single_ array, not the maximum amount of memory.  Concerning `SSIZE_MAX`: that is not defined in C, so best to cite your reference.

Comment: `SIZE_MAX` is also the maximum size of the portion of a C2011 `struct` up to but not including the last member, because it is the type of the result of the standard `offsetof()` macro.

Comment: @chux: standard C has a flat (von Neumann) memory model, and all of that memory may be treated as a single array (`((char *)0)[x]`). C compilers for Harvard (like most AVR and 8051 MCUs) , segmented (like 80286), or other systems often use non-standard language extensions to achieve access to the different areas of memory or introduce restrictions to language features to avoid some memory model issues. the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649018/what-is-the-difference-between-ssize-t-and-ptrdiff-t disagrees, but writev on with those imitations would be severely limited.

Comment: Post C stand references that support that.  By my reading there are none, so disagree with the unsupported "standard C has a flat (von Neumann) memory model, and all of that memory may be treated as a single array (((char *)0)[x])" and _only_ that model.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica More than a few years late, but `SSIZE_MAX` strongly implies a POSIX system, and while I'm not doing the digging necessary, I'm pretty sure among many other requirements beyond the C standard, POSIX does require a flat address space.  I think there's a bit of conflating POSIX and standard C going on. The `writev()` used above as an example is also a POSIX artifact, so any limitations that `writev()` would have outside of a POSIX-mandated flat address space isn't an argument against standard C support of non-flat memory models.